# Characteristic function of exponential and geometric distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

I'm trying to derive the characteristic function for exponential distribution and geometric distribution. Can you guide me on getting them?

Here is my solution so far:

Characteristic function of Exponential distribution:

$\phi(t) = E[e^{itX}]$ where $X$ has exponential distribution , then by definition, expectation can be written as: $$ \int_0^{\infty} e^{itx}  \lambda e^{-\lambda x } dx = \frac{\lambda}{it - \lambda} e^{(it - \lambda)x}\bigg|_0^{\infty} = \frac{\lambda}{ \lambda- it}$$

For the geometric random variables, assume $\Pr(X = 0) = P$, how can we find the characteristic function of $X$?

Here, since $X$ is a  discrete random variable, we have:

$\phi(t) =  E[e^{itX}] = \sum_{j = 0}^{\infty} e^{itj} (1 - P)^j P$ my issue is I don't know how to get a closed form for the characteristic function?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: how do we know that $it-\lambda<0$ in order the $\infty$ part to go to 0 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are almost there.

$$\phi(t) =  E[e^{itX}] = \sum_{j = 0}^{\infty} e^{itj} (1 - P)^j P = P \sum_{j = 0}^{\infty} [e^{it} (1 - P) ]^j $$

And now, if you don't know about the [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)  ( $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k$ ), it's  time to learn about it.

Answer (score 2):

- If $X$ is a random variable with density $f$ (with respect to Lebesgue measure on the real line) and $G$ is a well-behaved function, then 
  $$E[G(X)]=\int_{\Bbb R}G(x)f(x)d\lambda(x).$$

  In the particular case of the exponential law, this gives 
  $$\phi(t)=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{itx}e^{-\lambda x}\lambda dx.$$
- If $X$ is a random variable with values in the set of non-negative integers, then its characteristic function is given by 
  $$\phi(t):=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}e^{itk}P\{X=k\}.$$

Comment: Hi Davide, in my specific case, I wanted to see whether for the geometric or exponential characteristic functions, I can get a closed form. Is it enough to write the summation and not to get the closed form?

Comment: A closed form can be found, and I think it's what is expected.